# Сохранение значения переменной между запусками программы

Tags: python

Не знаю как правильно задать вопрос, но, например, у меня есть python файл с несколькими переменами

```
a = 's'
b = [5,7]
```

Я импортирую этот файл и меняю значение переменной

```
>>> import file2 as al
>>> print(al.a)
's'
>>> al.a = 'k'
```

Но мне нужно чтобы изменённое значение переменной сохранялось, т.е. при следующем запуске основного кода значение переменной сохранялось...

Как это реализовать? Прошу помощи)

Comment: Извините если мой вопрос не понятен)

Comment: Записывай в файл и считывай оттуда же

Comment: Вопрос понятен. Если во втором файле кроме переменных есть еще исполняемый код, то это странно - менять переписывать исполняемый код из другого кода. Создайте файл с переменными и используйте его в обоих файлах. Для этого есть специально обученные модули, например, configparser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы значение переменной/состояния программы сохранялось между вызовами программы, вам необходимо записать это состояние в файл, базу данных или иное хранилище.

В случае записи в `ini` файл, это может выглядеть так:

**Запись в файл**

```py
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('file.ini')

config['DEFAULT']['foo'] = 'foo value'
config['DEFAULT']['bar'] = 'bar value'

with open('file.ini', 'w') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
```

**Чтение**

```py
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('file.ini')

print(config['DEFAULT']['foo'])
print(config['DEFAULT']['bar'])
```

Comment: Что вы будете делать с двумя переменными? Два файла?

Comment: В двух файлах нет необходимости, можно сохранить в любом удобном формате - ini, json, xml. Но это уже выходит за рамки данного вопроса.

Comment: Это и есть вопрос. В вопросе речь о **нескольких** переменных.

Comment: Да, был не внимательным, подправлю ответ